# HttpContext null, codepath takes different thread

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, httpcontext

I have a situation where suddenly my HttpContext is null when accessing it via a class library. The class library, acting as a helper, contains a method to read the information and return it.

After digging in a bit deeper I found out the code is being executed on a different thread and I assume HttpContext is bound to a specific thread. In the  controller the HttpContext is available but when I access the HttpContext from the class library it turns up being null and in a different thread.

I would really like to find out why this is happening / how I approach finding the root cause of this behavior?

When I put a debug point on the GetTenantSession(), which happens the moment the UserManager.Find is executed, I can see that the thread changed, and the HttpContext is null.

My controller (with t,a,b,c used to debug)

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Index(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
  if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    return View(model);

  var t = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
  var a = (IDocumentSession)HttpContext.Items["RavenDB_TenantSession"];
  var b = (IDocumentSession)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Items["RavenDB_TenantSession"];
  var c = RavenContext.GetTenantSession();

  var user = UserManager.Find(model.Email, model.Password);

  return View();
}
```

RavenContext.cs (class library)

```
public class RavenContext
{
    public static IDocumentSession GetMasterSession()
        {
            return (IDocumentSession)HttpContext.Current.Items["RavenDB_MasterSession"];
        }       
        public static IDocumentSession GetTenantSession()
        {
            var t = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;            
            return (IDocumentSession)HttpContext.Current.Items["RavenDB_TenantSession"];
        }
        public static void InitTenantSession(string tenantDBName)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Items["RavenDB_TenantSession"] = GetDocumentStore().OpenSession(tenantDBName);
        }
        public static IDocumentStore GetDocumentStore()
        {
            return (IDocumentStore)HttpContext.Current.Items["RavenDB_DocumentStore"];
        }
}
```

UserManager, referencing the RavenContext.GetTenantSession

```
public class UserManager : UserManager<User>
    {
        public UserManager(IUserStore<User> store) : base(store){}

        public static UserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<UserManager> options, IOwinContext context)
        {
            var userStore = new UserStore<User>(RavenContext.GetTenantSession);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some code is missing form your example. You probably call 
`UserManager.Create()` on a different thread, probably on App.Startup ,
where HttpContext does not exist.
(Since it only exists when in a session between server-client).